# better views of javascript polluted global namespace

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to see what variables you (or other libraries) have polluted to the global namespace?

In the (chrome) debugger console, typing `this`/`this.window` reveals hundreds of objects, even without other libraries.

Is there a way to have it prune all of the standard browser space objects and return globals (or better, categorized by script file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run a script before any other scripts load, you can store a list of the built-int window properties:

```
var builtInProps = []
for(key in window){
    builtInProps.push(key);
}
```

Then after all your scripts load

```
var pollution = [];
for(key in window){
    // check to make sure this key is in builtInProps, otherwise push it to "pollution"
}
```

Comment: Uh, or use firebug like suggested by Mr. Schweiger.

Comment: This is a nice cross browser solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the Firebug plugin for FireFox ([http://getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/)/), look at the DOM tab. The global objects are in bold:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/9RHaIqoEV]

(this is from my browser where I'm currently unit testing a backbone.js app)

Answer (score 0):

http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/ Might do the trick. Shows a lot of good stuff, actually.